# Accessing the first elements in a array of Lists (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a large dataframe  `df_c` with a column `type_info1` each rows contains a list with two elements .

I need to access the first element of each list on the array object. Is there a quick way to do it directly on the dataframe without going through the for loop etc or maybe use `numpy` :

```
df_c.loc[:,'type_info1'].values
```

results :

```
array([list(['AB#5', 'XYZ/ABCD']), list(['TB#5', 'XYZ/ABCD']),
       list(['CD#5', 'XYZ/ABCD']), ..., list(['BF#5', 'XYZ/ABCD']),
       list(['GH#7', 'XYZ/ABCD']), list(['FL#5', 'XYZ/ABCD'])],
      dtype=object)
```

any suggestion is welcome. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an accessor: `df_c['type_info1'].str[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension for this:

`[item[0] for item in df_c.loc[:,'type_info1'].values]`

or perhaps zip:

`list(zip(*df_c.loc[:,'type_info1'].values))[0]`

Both of these assume that none of the lists are empty btw.

If some are empty and you could e.g. skip those in the list comprehension:

`[item[0] for item in df_c.loc[:,'type_info1'].values if item]`